# $\lambda$-eigenspace from matrix with row of zeroes

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently revising for my exam on Linear Algebra, and have reached a stump in a question regarding a $\lambda$-eigenspace taken from a $2\times2$ matrix with the bottom row consisting of zeroes.

The question says:

"Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the linear transformation $\phi\,:\,\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}-2&&5\\-1&&4\end{matrix}\right)$."

I have found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda=-1,$ or $\lambda=3$.

For $\lambda=-1$, I obtained the system $\left(\begin{matrix}
-1&&5\\-1&&5\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$.

and the coefficient matrix reduces to be $\left(\begin{matrix}-1&&5\\0&&0\end{matrix}\right)$.

In the solution to this question, my lecturer deduces that our $-1$-eigenspace is $\left\langle\left(\begin{matrix}5\\1\end{matrix}\right)\right\rangle$.

I am unsure as to how he came to this conclusion.

He defines in his notes the "$\lambda$-eigenspace of $f$" as the subspace $U_\lambda = \left\{u\in U\,:\,f(u)=\lambda u\right\}$. Now then, I know by the definition of span that $\left\langle\left(\begin{matrix}5\\1\end{matrix}\right)\right\rangle=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}5a\\a\end{matrix}\right)\,:\,a\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. I am however uncertain as to how this relates to the matrix I have acquired from the system.

My initial thoughts are: if $-x+5y=0$, then $x=5y$, so each vector takes a 'similar' form to his solution.

If anyone could offer insight I would be grateful. I would like to apologise in advance if a similar question has been asked before: I looked, but due to the 'niche' nature of the question, it was difficult to word effectively.

Comment: Everything you say sounds correct and it sounds like you understand everything perfectly well.  I'm not understanding where your confusion and apprehension comes from... You got to the line "then $x=5y$" in your description of your "initial thoughts" and there you have it.  Since we learned that $x=5y$, if we were to use a dummy variable / a parameter, say $a$ for example, and let $a=y$ then we learn that $x=5a$ and that $y=a$, in other words that the solution is of the form $\binom{5a}{a}$, and letting $a$ range over all possible values gives the result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems that I'm just tired, and didn't connect the dots so well!

Comment: I will point out and emphasize that there are infinitely many correct ways to describe a (nontrivial) subspace.  You could just as easily have called this $\left\langle\binom{1}{0.2}\right\rangle$ or something else.  It is possible for your answer to not exactly match the solution guide and still be perfectly correct.  Some ways are preferred over others depending on context.  Some people prefer having all the coefficients be integers if possible.  Others prefer the vectors be of unit length.  If multiple vectors are used some prefer them be orthogonal.  Those are all personal preference.